# Hibernating - Generating part of a composite key

Tags: java, hibernate, generator, composite-key

I have the following class:

```
@Entity
public class User {

    @Embeddable
    public static class Key implements Serializable {

        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

        private int id;

        @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
        private Date effectiveDate;

        @Column(unique = true)
        private String name;

        // Getters, Setters
    }

    @EmbeddedId
    private Key key;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String password;

    // Getters, Setters ...

}
```

I want the `id` field within `key` to be generated, unfortunately I can't find a way to do so. I've looked at similar questions here but I can't find the answer (all the solution proposed did not work in this case).

Comment: If every User has an ID that is automatically generated, the ID is sufficient to uniquely identify the user, and the effective date and the name don't have any reason to be part of the primary key. Do yourself a favor, and use single-column, purely technical, auto-generated IDs. You really don't want to update 25 foreign keys when the user name changes. And you really don't want 3 additional columns in every table that needs to have a foreign key to the User table.

Comment: I want the user to be able to change the username but I want to have a record of it, meaning having the same id and username but different effective date, this way I'll have a history of the name changes (or any other change for that matter).

Comment: You'd better store the history in another, separate table then.

Comment: Why is it simpler than generating the ID part? Two tables seems more complicated, I would love to hear your view about this.

Comment: It's simpler because all the tables that reference the user will keep pointing on the same row, with the same ID. The only different is that every time the user data changes, a new row in the history table will be inserted. It's a classical OneToMany association: one user has many history changes. That's BTW, the strategy that Hibernate Envers uses.

Comment: So one table will have just id as pk and the other table the same id + date of change?

Comment: Yes. Or better, the other table will also have an autogenerated ID, a foreign key to the User table, and an effective date field.

Comment: Learned something new, thanks!